# How to go around "Incorrect namespace usage(s)" in static tests

Tags: magento2, module, coding-standards, crud

I have a simple CRUD module for Magento 2.
When I run the static tests I get the following error/warning.

> "Incorrect namespace usage(s) found in file..... `<Vendor>_<Module>`".

The issue is caused by this line in my file

```
$resultPage->setActiveMenu('<Vendor>_<Module>::<menu_item_name_here>');
```

I also tried this approach:

```
const ADMIN_MENU = '<Vendor>_<Module>::<menu_item_name_here>';

...

$resultPage->setActiveMenu(self::ADMIN_MENU);
```

But I get the same result.
For core modules, this does not happen even if they have the same approach.

How can I get the static tests to shut up?

Ideally, I would like a clean solution, but I can go with "hiding the dirt under the rug".

Alternative: How can I set the active menu without upsetting the static tests?

Any clean approach would do.

Comment: I am tracking down the same issue...